# Price Calculator in javascript with escalating prices

Tags: javascript

I am looking to make price calculator for editing papers. I have the first part complete (words per day [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timbates328694678/g9fUf/82/) ).

```
<label>Need in how many Days</label>
<input type="number" id="days" />
<br />
<label>Total Word Count</label>
<input type="number" id="words" />
<br />
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" id="output" readonly />
```

I am looking to have the user enter the total word count and how many days they need the document, to display the price per project. I am not sure how to add the price table to the javascript and have it display the results. The table is:

250 words or less = $0.015 per word, 251-499 = $0.020 per word, 500-1499 = $0.025 per word, 1500-2499 = $0.030 per word, More than 2500 words per day = contact me

Thanks for the help. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: you're not "sure" how to do it: so how do you think to do it and why do you have doubts about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to do it as explicitly as possible in pure Javascript for easier understanding. 
This is the HTML:

```
<label>Need in how many Days</label>
<input type="number" onkeyup="getValues()" id="days" />
<br />
<label>Total Word Count</label>
<input type="number" onkeyup="getValues()" id="words" />
<br />
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" id="output" readonly />
<br />
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
var days, words, output;

//think of the prices as t-shirt sizes
var extraSmall = 0.015,
    small = 0.020,
    medium = 0.025,
    large = 0.030,
    extraLarge = 0.035,
    extraExtraLarge = 'contact me';

// now you go into the dom and get the values you need
window.getValues = function () {
    var pricePerWord = 0;
    days = document.getElementById('days').value;
    words = document.getElementById('words').value;

    if(words > 2500) {
        if(days == 1) {
            pricePerWord = extraExtraLarge;
        } else {
            pricePerWord = extraLarge;
        }
        } else if (words >= 1500) {
            pricePerWord = large;
        } else if (words >= 500) {
            pricePerWord = medium;
        } else if (words >= 251) {
            pricePerWord = small;
        } else {
            pricePerWord = extraSmall;
        }

    // call the calculate function to do the math and update the dom
    calculate(pricePerWord, words, days);
}

window.calculate = function (pricePerWord, words, days) {
    var total;
    if(pricePerWord === extraExtraLarge) {
        total = extraExtraLarge;
    } else {
        total = Math.ceil(pricePerWord * words / days);
    }
    output = document.getElementById('output');
    if(days !== '' && days != 0) {
        output.value = total;
    } else {
        output.value = 0; // prevent 'Nan' and 'Infinity' from showing up
    }
}
```

Note: The code uses 'window.calculate' as it makes it work in jsfidle but it should work without the 'window.' part in your code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you works great, how can I get this to not round up the result and display to the hundredths place 0.00?

Comment: Great, not sure if you just want ".00" at the end or just to get the actual value to 2 decimal places like ".23". If you want the later, replace 'total = Math.ceil(pricePerWord * words / days);' with 'total = Math.round(pricePerWord * words / days) / 100;'. If you just want to have a ".00" at the end, replace 'output.value = total;' with 'output.value = total + ".00";'